# Neural network and the law of large numbers

Tags: python, deep-learning, statistics

I am struggling to implement the following function in python, which holds by the law of large numbers:

[image]

where ANN stands for artificial neural network.

I have created a sample from where I have several subsamples. I want to feed each subsample at a time, increaigly, to train a neural network. That implies I will have a neural network for each subsample:

ANN((X_t,N,\theta_1,1)+ANN(X_t,N,\theta_2,2)+....

And each needs to be incorporated in a sum.

However I have no idea on how to implement this, once I would need to store, not the values but the neural network itself after each computation. Is there any references on how to solve a problem of this kind? I have looked at the recurrent neural networks implemented in Python, namely the LSTM, but that does not "store" each neural network, furthemore it selects the variablles that are more meaningful across time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

By invoking (artificial) neural networks and the Central Limit Theorem you step into quite a few concepts. Let me try to elaborate on these concepts before trying to suggest a solution.

First, the fact that

[image]

holds P-almost surely for a family of random variables *X_{1},X_{2}*,... that are iid (independently and identically distributed) like the random variable *X* is called the Strong Law of Large Numbers ([LLN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers#Strong_law)). In contrast, the Central Limit Theorem ([CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Classical_CLT)) refers to the limiting distribution (as the name suggests) which is Gaussian. Both theorems require proper scaling, namely [image: $\frac{1}{N}$] for the LLN

and [image: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$] for the CLT, respectively. Both theorems allow approximation through a finite sum of up to *J* summands which is what you attempt. However, equality is lost and approximate equality i.e. ≈ is appropriate. Moreover, there is no normalization in your summation which will cause the term to diverge. Note that the limits hold for certain functions being applied to *X*. You assume that the function ANN(X_t, N, Θ, j).

Second, the (artificial) neural network. Like any statistical model, a neural network takes in data input *X*, hyperparameters that determine the network architecture (e.g. depth and size of the involved layers) that might be *N* in your case, and a parameter vector *Θ*. The latter is only obtained after the model has been trained on data. In turn, I'd interpret your function

> def ANN(X_t, N, Θ)

as the inference function that compiles a previously trained neural network by combining hyperparameter value *N* the parameter vector *Θ* and applies it to the current data input *X_{t}*. However, you don't clarify what the input *j* is. *j* and *Θ_j* seem to suggest a recurrent neural network (RNN). An LSTM is a special type of RNN. However, it is unclear what the inputs actually are as you leave this vague. RNNs are used on speech, text, and numeric time-series data. This is further complicated by the fact that $X_{t}$ is on the left-hand side in the expectation and on the right-hand side as the input to the neural network.

Finally, the suggested solution. If the ANNs are in fact independent and you meant to write *E(Y)*, then your equation vaguely describes ensemble learning. There, several neural networks (of the same architecture) are trained on the same dataset and their prediction is averaged (not summed) to gain a more accurate prediction of the expectation of Y. If, on the other hand, you do describe RNNs, the equation above for *E(X)* vaguely describes a convergence of non-independent random variables as *X_{t+1}* and *Θ_{t+1}* depend on the previous *X_t*'s and *Θ_t*'s. Intuitively, you try to show that the output of an RNN converges to some numeric value when applied iteratively. Mathematically speaking, there are LLM-like results for non-iid random variables but they impose other very specific assumptions e.g. on the type of dependence.

Regarding storing neural networks. You can implement your own ANN program which is a lot of work (as it requires training and inference functions). Virtually every deep learning framework in Python allows storing/loading a parameter vector *Θ* which would allow you to implement your procedure regardless of what mathematical meaning you'd like to derive from it. In keras, for example, a model can be saved via

```
model.save(PARAMETER_PATH)
```

and later re-loaded via

```
keras.models.load_model(PARAMETER_PATH)
```

see the [reference](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize). Similar methods exist for [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html) another very popular deep learning framework in Python.